# How to store (and query) the MaxMind GeoIP2 database in Azure?

Tags: azure, maxmind

In an [Azure Web App](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-web-overview/) I need to efficiently query the [MaxMind GeoIP2 City Database](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip2-city) (due to the volume of queries and the latency requirements we cannot use the MaxMind's rest API).

I'm wondering what's the best approach for storing the db (binary MMDB format, accessed via the [official .NET api](https://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/downloadable/)) so that it's easy to update with minimal downtime (we are going to subscribe Monthly updates) and still cost effective as to what regards Azure storage and transactions.

Apparently block blobs are the way to go, but I'm not sure about the monthly updates and the fact that the GeoIP2 api load in memory the whole db (I do not know if this would be a problem for the Web App, if I need a web worker to keep it up or I need something else), but actually I do not know yet how large the file is.

What's the most cost effective solution that preserve low latency over a huge volume?

Comment: cost effective solution will be azure table storage. if you can get the partitionkey rowkey combo right latency should not be an issue. am not sure of the format in which you get the db. If it is csv , I came across this library which eases storing csv data to azure table storage. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/08/03/converting-between-azure-tables-and-csv/

Comment: @Aravind - I don't see how table storage solves the issue of storing a binary database file. I don't think the question is about converting the content from one format to another. Even using the csv version, you'd still need to copy data back out of table storage to local disk in order to use its content via the api. Also: Table storage and blob storage have the exact same per-GB cost.

Comment: @David Right. In any case you would still have to keep the database up to date as and when the source provides you an update. If it is binary then block blobs is the option. also don't think loading the whole db in memory is a good choice.

Comment: @Aravind - There's no choice regarding loading the entire db into memory: This is how the SDK works, according to the docs. Unless the OP forks/modifies the SDK, that's a moot point.

Comment: FWIW, the default for the API is not to store the entire database in memory but to use a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [API docs](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-dotnet/) you must have the database available in a file system (the API doesn't know anything about Azure storage and related REST API). So, regardless where you permanently store it, you'll need to have it on a disk somewhere.

I have no idea how large the database footprint is, but Web Apps, Cloud Services (web/worker roles) and Virtual Machines (whether Linux or Windows) all have local disks. And you have read/write access to these disks. So, you'd need to copy the database binary file (or csv) to local disk from somewhere. At this point, when you initialize the SDK, you'd create a `DatabaseReader` and point it to your locally-downloaded copy of the database file.

You mentioned storing the database in blob storage. There's nothing stopping you from doing so and simply downloading a copy to local disk. And there's nothing stopping you from storing multiple versions in multiple blobs. Note: You may also take advantage of Azure File storage (an SMB share). Which you choose is up to you.

As far as most cost effective solution: You'll need to do the pricing workup yourself to see what's most effective. You'd also need to evaluate how much RAM is available for the given size VM/role instance/Web App you choose. You mentioned Web Apps in your question: Web App instances scale from 0.5GB to 14GB, depending on the tier you choose (again, you'll need to evaluate this).

Comment: Will azure file storage help in this case? I haven't checked it's pricing though.

Comment: File Storage is fine as well, but likely won't offer the same performance as a local-disk file, for initial read purposes (and I have no clue if that matters).

Comment: This is not a good idea, the database reader only takes a stream and doesn't give you an option for using in memory database, only memory mapped over blob storage.... not a good idea